# Shared Pointer to Anonymous Structure

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

Is it possible to create a shared_ptr to an *anonymous struct? *I'm not quite sure if the struct below constitutes an anonymous struct. For example;

```
struct { HWND hwnd; } *tmpArgs;
tmpArgs->hwnd = hwnd;

std::shared_ptr<struct> evtArgs(tmpArgs); // possible? right now its a compile error "'struct': missing tag name"

// usage
evtHandler( evtArgs ); // evtHandler( std::weak_ptr<void> EventArguments );
```

I have a very narrow/specialised case where I need to pass a structure `tmpArgs` that is not going to be used anywhere else in the application. So I dont need to declare a new `struct` type.

Comment: Note: What do you think the value of `tmpArgs` is, when this code runs? (The value of the pointer itself - i.e. what does it point to?)

Answer (score 3):

You can get the `shared_ptr` you crave...

`std::shared_ptr<std::remove_pointer<decltype(tmpArgs)>::type> evtArgs(tmpArgs);`

but you're not going to be able to pass it out of the scope of this code in any useful way.

Potentially, this would be useful if you're trying to ensure that the class is only ever referenced via the `shared_ptr` or a `weak_ptr`, and so you're putting this stuff at namespace scope. But that seems a stretch away from good coding style to me.

Comment: I think you can simplify that to `std::shared_ptr<decltype(*tmpArgs)> evtArgs{tmpArgs};`. Actually with C++17 you probably can just: `std::shared_ptr evtArgs{tmpArgs};`.

Comment: That's true, in this case `decltype(*tmpArgs)` is the same as `std::remove_ptr<decltype(tmpArgs)>`.

Comment: I don't believe C++17 allows deduction of a `std::shared_ptr` type from a raw pointer, as (per https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/deduction_guides and https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/how-to-use-class-template-argument-deduction/), the template cannot distinguish an array and non-array from a raw pointer, and they need to go into different places.